# SimpleCursorAdapter и первая строка с _id = 0

Tags: android, sqlite

Имеется код:

```
    DB = new DataBase(getActivity());
    DB.open();
    cursor = DB.getPositions();
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_item, cursor, new String[] {DataBase.Name}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0)
```

Часть из DB:

```
Cursor getPositions() {
    return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE, null);
}
```

Как при объявлении scAdapter в строке new String[] {DataBase.Name} заставить прочитать только первую строку с _id = 0? Грубо говоря необходимо читать не один столбец, а несколько, но только первые строки.
Заранее количество столбцов неизвестно.

Comment: есть такой оператор WHERE в языке SQL. C его помощью можно указать условия попадания в выборку для запроса: `"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE _id = 0"` - получить все столбцы таблицы у которых столбец _id = 0.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, немного не успел вперёд вас написать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения за некорректный вопрос, суть вопроса заключалась в том, как в адаптере указать наименования столбцов, которые периодически добавляются в виде P1, P2 и т.д.
DB.java

```
Cursor getPositions() {
    return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE + " WHERE _id = 0", null);
}
```

Fragment.java

```
  cursor = DB.getPositions();
  String[] from = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()]; // создаём массив, размерность которого равна количеству столбцов.
  for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) { 
       from [i] = "P" + i; // в массив заносим названия столбцов, получается P1, P2, P3 и т.д.
       }
  scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.s.imple_item, cursor, from, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0); //объявляем адаптер и вносим туда известные нам названия столбцов.
```